# How would I go on about to Left Factor the following productions?

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

Given:

5 Non Terminals: S, A, B, C, D

6 Terminals: t, (, ), [, ], =

```
S - > A | B

A - > t ( D )

B -> C = D

C - > t [ D ]
```

How would I go about left factoring this? I know I have to left factor for t but it seems tricky as an example. If I do:

```
S - > A | B

A - > E

B -> C = D

C - > E

E - > tF

F - > ( D ) | [ D ]
```

It would mean A could evaluate to A -> t [ D ] which is wrong

Comment: Aside: I don't think you have a good handle on what `terminal` means.

Comment: Im sorry, it was a typo